# In a Activity Diagram, how do I reference an external acitivity?

Tags: uml

Lets say I have an activity diagram, modeling a certain process, which uses other processes which need to be modeled as a seperate activity: How do I reference that second activity within my first activity diagram?

Is there a certain symbol used to reference an separate activity from within an activity diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you mean is the CallBehaviourAction I assume. To indicate this, put a fork symbol inside the action that references the activity( see [UML Superstructure Spec, Section 12.3.14](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/Superstructure/PDF/)). Furthermore, you can add the name of the called activity to the in some notation that makes sense in your case (e.g., some fullqualified name if your activities are adressed like that).